# What is the difference between the lists

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I have two lists obtained in the same way, only the first is read directly from the list, and the second is unloaded from postgresql:

List1

```
>>> print(type(list1))
... <class 'list'>
>>> print(list1)
... [array([-0.11152368,  0.1186936 ,  0.00150046, -0.0174517 , -0.14383622,
            0.04046987, -0.07069934, -0.09602138,  0.18125986, -0.14305925])]
>>> print(type(list1[0][0]))
... <class 'numpy.float64'>
```

---

List2

```
>>> print(type(list2))
... <class 'tuple'>
>>> print(list2)
... (['-0.03803351', '0.07370875', '0.03514577', '-0.07568369', '-0.07438357'])
>>> list2 = list(list2)
>>> print(type(list2))
... <class 'list'>
>>> print(list2)
... [['-0.03803351', '0.07370875', '0.03514577', '-0.07568369', '-0.07438357']]
>>> print(type(list2[0][0]))
... <class 'str'>
```

How do I see the difference in the elements? How can I get items like `<class 'numpy.float64'>` from list2?

And why is the type list1 a class 'list' if it's `numpy`?

Comment: Your code tells you exactly what the difference is: the first is a list containing an array of numpy float64s, the second is a tuple containing a list of strings.

Comment: And why is the type list1 a class 'list' if it's numpy? - where do you see that?

Comment: type(list1[0]) is a numpy.array.

Comment: How?, you have cotes then that will mean it's a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list1` is a `list` that contains 1 element that is an `numpy.array` that contains multiple `floats64`.

`list2` is `list` that contains 1 element that is a `list` that contains multiple 
 `strings` (that happen to look a lot like `floats`).

You can convert them like so:

```
import numpy as np

# list of list of strings that look like floats
list2 = [['-0.03803351', '0.07370875', '0.03514577', '-0.07568369', '-0.07438357']]

# list of np.arrays that contain float64's
data = list([np.array(list(map(np.float64, list2[0])))])  # python 3.x

print(data)
print(type(data))
print(type(data[0]))
print(type(data[0][0]))
```

Output:

```
[array([-0.03803351,  0.07370875,  0.03514577, -0.07568369, -0.07438357])]
<type 'list'>
<type 'numpy.ndarray'>
<type 'numpy.float64'>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I did not succeed. print(data) = [array(<map object at 0x7f08d0690e80>, dtype=object)], accordingly, print (data [0] [0]), indicates the absence of this index.

Comment: @Vasai in python 3 `map` returns a generator - simply stuff it inside a list to get to what output I had - fixed code.

Comment: Sorry, I can not understand the numpy module at all, I'm trying to write a loop, I get only the last item in the list, how to add to the list and not replace?

Comment: @Vasai why using numpy then? `data` is a list wiht 1 element that is a ndarray. you can use `myfloats = data[0].tolist()` to get a normal list of floats . see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html

Answer (score -1):

As [Patrick Artner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7505395/patrick-artner) wrote. If list2 contains multiple arrays, you can use:

```
   def string_list_to_int_list(l):
       return l.astype(float)

   converted_list = list(map(string_list_to_int_list, list2))
```